# Reverted diagonal dots

Tags: support, mathjax

At a certain point I had to write $\ddots$ reverted. I tried the \reflectbox{$\ddots$} but I got no success. Is there any alternative to write this symbol here in MSE?

Thanks

Comment: I recall looking for this when trying to write power towers... The TeX command is `\iddots`, but: $\iddots$ it doesn't work in MathJax.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Sorry, what doesn't work?...$\def\iddots{{\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu 
\raise12mu{.}}}$

Comment: (Use `$\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}$`)$\def\iddots{{\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}}}$

Comment: ' x^{x^{\iddots^{x}}}'  for $x^{x^{{\iddots}^{x}}}$?

Comment: (You should put your code between two ` symbols, then it won't render and goes all lilac.)

Comment: @user1729 I suppose someone defined `\iddots` in one of their comments. It's not native to MJ, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A much simpler way is to just use Unicode, which is natively supported by MathJax. The unicode symbol for "up right diagonal ellipsis" is `U+22F0`, as seen [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22f0/index.htm). If your keyboard and operating system supports typing in unicode directly, then good for you. Otherwise you can just copy from the website above.

*Edit*: Or, as robjohn observed, you can use `\unicode{x22F0}` to access the unicode character using MathJax.

Examples:

- `$⋰$` gives $⋰$
- `$$x^{x^{⋰^{x}}}$$` gives $$x^{x^{⋰^{x}}}$$
- `$\unicode{x22f0}$` gives $\unicode{x22f0}$ also

Comment: This is displayed as a black box on my phone (although it worked fine on my computer).

Comment: (+1) I just found this and came back to this question, only to find you had already posted :-)

Comment: $\unicode{x22F0}$ can also be achieved with `\unicode{x22F0}`. e.g. `x^{x^{\unicode{x22F0}^{x}}}` produces $$x^{x^{\unicode{x22F0}^{x}}}$$

Answer (score 6):

The $\LaTeX$ command you want is `\iddots`. However, this doesn't work with MathJax. Instead, you can use the following.

`\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}`

This gives $x^{x^{\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}^x}}$, but the raw code is then the following.

`$x^{x^{\kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.}^x}}$`

This code ain't pretty!

Comment: iddots $\iddots$ seems to work for me.

Comment: It only works on this page.

Comment: ahha! very subtle.

Comment: @Daniel: You can find hints for that in the first comment to the original question. If you examine the source code you'll see that user1729 defined the command in the second comment. If there are sufficiently many upvoted comments so that comment is hidden, the `\iddots` won't work anymore unless you "show all comments".

Comment: @Asaf Incidentally, is there any chance they will ever fix the scoping of Mathjax so that these kinds of things don't happen?