# MathJax and iddots / udots or reflectbox

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax

I wanted to actually sketch a matrix and needed the flipped version of $\ \ddots\ $, but I can't find a way to do it.

Tried reflectbox iddots udots and all the crazy stuff you find somewhere at [TSE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Can somebody help me?

For everybody searching for a workaround U+22F0 $⋰$ is actually "working" but it seems a bit unloved, tiny and not well spaced compared to it's brother U+22F1 $⋱$ (This has actually to do with the math-environment)

Comment: You might want to read http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html#character-fallbacks, especially the end of that section

Comment: I don't know what font is actually used inside the math-environment and how "I" could help fixing it on a meta-global level.

Comment: I can't be the only one who read "mathjax and idiots".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I actually enjoy MathJax a bunch and the whole system.
That's why I don't just toss the table and try to find an easy (local) workaround, but instead the community to help me and maybe get it changed, for future users!

Comment: Definitely I've observed some things that fit neatly under the heading of "MathJax and idiots", but I'm not sure they're worth posting about. $\qquad$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverted diagonal dots](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/reverted-diagonal-dots)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu
}}
```

This is based off the actual definition of `\ddots` in $\rm\TeX$, which constructs the character from three separate dots like this.

Then the result for `\iddots` is
$\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{\kern1mu\raise1pt{.}\kern2mu\raise4pt{.}\kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}\kern1mu}}\iddots$ rather than $\unicode{x22F0}$.  Compare to `\ddots`: $\ddots$

Comment: You did a little typo in the last line you wrote `\ddots` instead of `\iddots`in the last line.

And I thought it wasn't possible to use newcommand inside stackexchange itself. Thanks.

Comment: Since I am unable to edit / view your post, I am not able to verify or repeat this. Tried it in the post itself and it straight up didn't worked.

Comment: When I copy it the same way as in the quoted text in post, I get an error which says: "Extra close brace or missing open brace" (In the post preview. Not in a comment.)  When I remove the last } i get: $\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu}
}\iddots$ (Which is, up to the new lines, probably the same thing as in the source of your post.)

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Even if you cannot edit post you should be able to see the source [like this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/23276/revisions) or [like this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3b78f814-3e2b-4695-a229-dab8fe00f5f5/view-source). For testing, you can use and appropriate [meta-tag:sandbox]. (At least in one of the sandboxes the answers there are CW, you should probably be able to edit any of them. Or you can post a new answer in the Formatting Sandbox.)

Comment: @PatrickAbraham, thanks for pointing out the typos.  I've fixed them.  Yes, you can use `\newcommand` and `\def` in StackExchange, through it is not encouraged because it can affect other posts.  But if you are adding a missing standard command, I think people would be OK with it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for the report about the extra brace.  I have fixed in the post.  I copied it from a working example, but missed the one at the end of the second-to-last line and thought I had missed one while copying, so added it in.  Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham I will add [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page) to accompany Davide Cervone's comment that newcommand should be used carefully here. (Mainly not in the titles.) You can probably find a few other posts discussing use of newcommand here on meta.

Comment: _" you can use \newcommand and \def in StackExchange, through it is not encouraged because it can affect other posts"_ Ouch! That's kind of a nasty threat.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf, see the link in Martin's comment for a discussion of the situation and its potential solutions.

Comment: @DavidCervone Thanks for the pointer.